# How to use exponential smoothing to smooth the timeseries in python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, signal-processing, forecasting

I am trying to use exponential smooting to smooth a timeseries.

Suppose my timeseries looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [446.6565,  454.4733,  455.663 ,  423.6322,  456.2713,  440.5881, 425.3325,  485.1494,  506.0482,  526.792 ,  514.2689,  494.211 ]
index= pd.date_range(start='1996', end='2008', freq='A')
oildata = pd.Series(data, index)
```

I want to get the smoothed version of that timeseries.

If I did something like this;

```
from statsmodels.tsa.api import ExponentialSmoothing    
fit1 = SimpleExpSmoothing(oildata).fit(smoothing_level=0.2,optimized=False)
fcast1 = fit1.forecast(3).rename(r'$\alpha=0.2$')
```

it only outputs the forcasted three values, but not the smoothed version of my original timeseries. Is there a way to get the smoothed version of my original timeseries?

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the smoothed values in the `fittedvalues` attribute of the model, apparently.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [446.6565,  454.4733,  455.663 ,  423.6322,  456.2713,  440.5881, 425.3325,  485.1494,  506.0482,  526.792 ,  514.2689,  494.211 ]
index= pd.date_range(start='1996', end='2008', freq='A')
oildata = pd.Series(data, index)

from statsmodels.tsa.api import SimpleExpSmoothing
fit1 = SimpleExpSmoothing(oildata).fit(smoothing_level=0.2,optimized=False)
# fcast1 = fit1.forecast(3).rename(r'$\alpha=0.2$')

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(oildata)
plt.plot(fit1.fittedvalues)
plt.show()
```

It yields:

[image]

The [documentation](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters.HoltWintersResults.html) states:

> fittedvalues: ndarray
>
> An array of the fitted values. Fitted by the Exponential Smoothing model.

Note that you can also use the `fittedfcast` attribute which contains all values + the first forecast, or the `fcastvalues` attribute which contains the forecast only.

Comment: thanks a lot. what does it mean by fitted values? is it the smoothed version of the timeseries? :)

Comment: That is what I would strongly think, especially as the first point is the same and the series lenght is the same. EDIT also this is not an array but a series apparently, the index is the same - I included a link to the documentation of the `fit` object type, which is a `HoltWintersResults`.

Comment: Fitted values are the in-sample predictions of the model based on the fitted parameters.

Answer (score 2):

[`ExponentialSmoothing`](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters.ExponentialSmoothing.html#statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters.ExponentialSmoothing) is not to a tool to smoothen time series data, it is a *time series forecasting method*.

> The fit() function will return an instance of the HoltWintersResults class that contains the learned coefficients. The forecast() or the predict() function on the result object can be called to make a forecast.

So by calling `predict`, what the class will doing is providing a forecast using the learned coefficients.

In order to smoothen the time series however, you can use the `fittedvalues` attribute, as @smarie points out

---

However, I'd go with a more appropriate tool, such as a `savgol_filter`:

```
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter
savgol_filter(oildata, 5, 3)

array([444.87816   , 461.58666   , 444.99296   , 441.70785143,
       442.40769143, 438.36852857, 441.50125714, 472.05622571,
       512.20891429, 521.74822857, 517.63141429, 493.37037143])
```

As mentioned in the comments, the savgol filter performs a local taylor approximation of a given `polyorder` on a given window size (`window_length`) and results in a smoothing of the time series.

Here's what it would look like with the above set up:

```
plt.plot(oildata)
plt.plot(pd.Series(savgol_filter(oildata, 5, 3), index=oildata.index))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot. I like your suggestion of using `savgol_filter`. Do you know what is the difference between savgol_filter and moving average? :)

Comment: Savgol filter from what I remember performs a local taylor approximation on a given window size and results in a smoothing of the function @emj

Comment: Wheareas a moving average is just a mean, as its name says @emj

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found the detials you have posted in savgol filter very useful. Thank you :)

Comment: I am trying `lowess` smoothing techniques in addition to `savgol filter`. I got some issues. I thought that you would be able to help me. My question is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60985292/how-to-smooth-timeseries-with-yearly-data-with-lowess-in-python Please let me know your thoughts. Thank you :)

Comment: Will give it a look when I have some time :) @EmJ