# How to smooth timeseries with yearly data with lowess in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, seaborn, smoothing

I have some data that were recoreded yearly as follows.

```
mydata = [0.6619346141815186, 0.7170140147209167, 0.692265510559082, 0.6394098401069641, 0.6030995845794678, 0.6500746607780457, 0.6013327240943909, 0.6273292303085327, 0.5865356922149658, 0.6477396488189697, 0.5827181339263916, 0.6496025323867798, 0.6589270234107971, 0.5498126149177551, 0.48638370633125305, 0.5367399454116821, 0.517595648765564, 0.5171639919281006, 0.47503289580345154, 0.6081966757774353, 0.5808742046356201, 0.5856912136077881, 0.5608134269714355, 0.6400936841964722, 0.6766082644462585]

corresponding_year = [1970,1971,1972,1973,1974,1975,1976,1977,1978,1979,1980,1981,1982,1983,1984,1985,1986,1987,1988,1989,1990,1991,1992,1993,1994]]
```

I used `statsmodels` python package to calculate lowess as follows.

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
lowess = sm.nonparametric.lowess

z = lowess(x, y, frac= 1./3, it=3)
```

The output I got was as follows.

```
      [[1.96000000e+03, 6.95703548e-01],
       [1.96100000e+03, 6.81750671e-01],
       [1.96200000e+03, 6.68002318e-01],
       [1.96300000e+03, 6.55138324e-01],
       [1.96400000e+03, 6.38960761e-01],
       [1.96500000e+03, 6.25042177e-01],
       [1.96600000e+03, 6.18586936e-01],
       [1.96700000e+03, 6.17026334e-01],
       [1.96800000e+03, 6.14565102e-01],
       [1.96900000e+03, 6.17610340e-01],
       [1.97000000e+03, 6.20404414e-01],
       [1.97100000e+03, 6.10193222e-01],
       [1.97200000e+03, 5.90100648e-01],
       [1.97300000e+03, 5.70935248e-01],
       [1.97400000e+03, 5.47818726e-01],
       [1.97500000e+03, 5.25788570e-01],
       [1.97600000e+03, 5.18661218e-01],
       [1.97700000e+03, 5.28921300e-01],
       [1.97800000e+03, 5.42783400e-01],
       [1.97900000e+03, 5.55425915e-01],
       [1.98000000e+03, 5.71486587e-01],
       [1.98100000e+03, 5.91539778e-01],
       [1.98200000e+03, 6.13021691e-01],
       [1.98300000e+03, 6.34508409e-01],
       [1.98400000e+03, 6.57703989e-01]]
```

However, I am not clear what are the two values I get in `statsmodel`. Is there something I make wrong. Moreover, I would also like to know what the two paramers `frac` and `it` do?

Moreover, I would also like to plot the smoothed timeseries using `seaborn`. It seems like seaborn supports `lowess`. However, it does not have the `frac` and `it` parameters. See the code below.

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.01)
ytrue = np.exp(-x / 5) + 2 * np.sin(x / 3)
y = ytrue + np.random.normal(size=len(x))

sns.regplot(x, y, lowess=True)
```

In that case, is it possible to draw `regplot` in `seaborn` using `statmodels` output?

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [lowess](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.nonparametric.smoothers_lowess.lowess.html) result can be plotted as shown in the code below. Note that `lowess()` first argument is the `y`-value (`endog`) and the second is the `x` (`exog`). The default result has `z[:,0]` being the sorted `x`-values and `z[:,1]` the corresponding estimated `y`-values.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np

mydata = [0.6619346141815186, 0.7170140147209167, 0.692265510559082, 0.6394098401069641, 0.6030995845794678, 0.6500746607780457, 0.6013327240943909, 0.6273292303085327, 0.5865356922149658, 0.6477396488189697, 0.5827181339263916, 0.6496025323867798, 0.6589270234107971, 0.5498126149177551, 0.48638370633125305, 0.5367399454116821, 0.517595648765564, 0.5171639919281006, 0.47503289580345154, 0.6081966757774353, 0.5808742046356201, 0.5856912136077881, 0.5608134269714355, 0.6400936841964722, 0.6766082644462585]
corresponding_year = [1970,1971,1972,1973,1974,1975,1976,1977,1978,1979,1980,1981,1982,1983,1984,1985,1986,1987,1988,1989,1990,1991,1992,1993,1994]

x = np.array(corresponding_year)
y = np.array(mydata)
z = sm.nonparametric.lowess(y, x, frac= 1./3, it=3)

plt.plot(x, y, color='dodgerblue')
plt.plot(z[:,0], z[:,1], 'ro-')

plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

PS: To compare to the seaborn `regplot` on the same plot, call it as:

```
sns.regplot(x, y, lowess=True, ax=plt.gca())
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Please let me know what the two parameters `frac` and `it` does? Looking forward to hearing from you :)

Comment: `frac=1/3` seems to mean that one third of all data is considered when evaluating the estimation of one point (default `frac=2/3`). `it=3` means the weighting is improved 3 times. More info in the [notes](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.nonparametric.smoothers_lowess.lowess.html) and at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_regression).